# Matlab inspector will not list object properties of subclass

Tags: matlab

I'm using Matlab 2017a and have a subclass inhering from the serial class. After creating an object of the subclass I cannot see the additional subclass properties. For example `inspect(subclassobject)` or `properties(subclassobject)` will only list the properties for the super-class serial. It is still possible to use dot notation `subclassobject.property` to view or change property values, but the set and get functions will produce errors stating the subclass property is not an accessible instance of class 'serial port objects'. I've included my class definition and constructor.

```matlab
classdef subclass < serial
    properties 
        prop_1
    end
    methods
        % Constructor
        function obj = subclass(port)
            obj = obj@serial(port);
            %port is a string ex. 'com3' that is necessary for
            %constructing the serial class
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `serial` class overloads the `subsref` method, which is the method that is called when you index into an object, for example using `myobject.myproperty` or `myobject(1)`. And looking at the code (`toolbox\matlab\serial\@serial\subsref.m`), it doesn't seem to do it in a very clean way.

For this reason, you're going to have difficulty when subclassing `serial`, unless you *also* implement `subsref` on your subclass. Implementing `subsref` properly is a world of pain. Just my 2c, but in my opinion MathWorks probably should have made `serial` a Sealed class, so that you couldn't even attempt to subclass it.

I would guess that you'll continue to have similar issues (and I think I saw another similar question a few days ago, that may have been from you, indicating that perhaps you're already finding this).

I would recommend that you *don't* subclass `serial`. Instead, create a class that *wraps* `serial`, something like the following:

```
classdef MyClass
    properties (Hidden, Access = private)
        myserialobject
    end
    properties
        mySubClassProp1
        mySubClassProp2
        %...
    end
    properties (Dependent)
        mySerialProp1
        mySerialProp2
        %...
    end
    methods
        function obj = MyClass(port)
            obj.myserialobject = serial(port);
            % Set other subclass props
        end
    end
    methods
        function val = get.mySerialProp1(obj)
            val = obj.myserialobject.mySerialProp1;
        end
        function obj = set.mySerialProp1(obj, val)
            obj.myserialobject.mySerialProp1 = val;
        end
        %... pass through get and set for each serial prop you need to access
        function obj = mySerialMethod1(obj, varargin)
            mySerialMethod1(obj.myserialobject, varargin{:});
        end
        %... pass through method for each serial method you need to access
    end
end
```

Basically you have a class, which has a `serial` object as a property, and has a bunch of properties and methods of its own as well. Whenever you need to access a property of the `serial` object, make a Dependent property with `get` and `set` methods that just pass through the value to or from the underlying `serial` object. Similarly, if you need to access a method of the `serial` object, create a method on your class that just passes the call through to the underlying `serial` object.

This pattern uses *composition* rather than *inheritance*. That's often (not always) a good practice anyway, but in this case it will also save you all the issues you're finding with the overloaded `subsref`.